# Spring Security WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter: AuthenticationManagerBuilder - override configure method or autowire globalUserDetails?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Dear community: I'm writing this to ask how I have to configure **AuthenticationManagerBuilder**.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
  @Autowired
  private UserDetailsService secUserDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  private PasswordEncoder secPasswordEncoder;

  . . .

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
  }

  @Autowired
  public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(secUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(secPasswordEncoder);
  }

  @Bean
  public DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider() {
    DaoAuthenticationProvider authenticationProvider = new DaoAuthenticationProvider();
    authenticationProvider.setUserDetailsService(secUserDetailsService);
    authenticationProvider.setPasswordEncoder(secPasswordEncoder);
    return authenticationProvider;
  }
}
```

Which implementation should I have to follow between

```
  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
      auth.authenticationProvider(authenticationProvider());
  }
```

and

```
  @Autowired
  public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(secUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(secPasswordEncoder);
  }
```

Plus, I found that if I comment whole **'@Override protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)** method, my application works well but when I commented **@Autowired public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)**, following error occurred :

```
o.s.s.o.p.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.handleException:169 - Handling error: IllegalStateException, UserDetailsService is required.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UserDetailsService is required.
    at org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter$UserDetailsServiceDelegator.loadUserByUsername(WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.java:464)
    at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.loadUserDetails(UserDetailsByNameServiceWrapper.java:68)
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider.java:103)
    at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175)
...
```

Which method should I have to use? Additionally,(this is my biggest matter of concern) is there any **performance issues** if I use both?

Comment: does it work if you comment out both the `AuthenticationManager` bean and the `globalUserDetails` method, leaving only the `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder)` method?

Comment: @pero_hero Then application failed to start : Field authenticationManager in AuthorizationServerConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager' that could not be found. Error mentioned above (o.s.s.o.p.endpoint.TokenEndpoint) occurred when I call refreshToken API.

Comment: what happens if you change the `configure` method to do the same as the `globalUserDetails` method: `auth.userDetailsService(secUserDetailsService).passwordEncoder(secPasswordEncoder)`?

Comment: @pero_hero same error occurred. (```UserDetailsService``` is required). Btw, I found some helpful link : https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/4571. But still not sure using both of them doesn't cause any performance issue. It seems Okay so far tho :p

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to this [guide](https://spring.io/guides/topicals/spring-security-architecture)

the difference between using

`@Override` `configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)`

and

an `@Autowired` `AuthenticationManagerBuilder` into a method

is that the first one is creating a local `AuthenticationManager` which delegates to the default spring-security parent `AuthenticationManager` if it is not able to handle the authentication request, whereas the latter one (using `@Autowired`) configures a new global `AuthenticationManager` instance.

So using the `globalUserDetails` is perfectly ok, but there is no need to use both as you would create a local one which is delegating to the same as the parent, which is useless.